# wrong with wp_generate_attachment_metadata()

Tags: php, wordpress, upload

It works (upload , send to db) but

`wp_generate_attachment_metadata()` returns bad letters whene file uploaded !

some of the wrong charechters :

```
����JFIF��;CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v62), quality = 90 ��C     ��C       ����"��   ���}!1AQa"q2���#B��R��$3br� %&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz���������������������������������������������������������������������������    ���w!1AQaq"2�B����  #3R�br� $4�
```

the code :

```
if (isset($_FILES['ed_header_logo'] ) && !empty($_FILES['ed_header_logo']['name']) )
{
    $filename = $_FILES['ed_header_logo']['name'];
    $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype( basename($filename), null );
    $wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();

    move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['ed_header_logo']['tmp_name'], $wp_upload_dir['path']  . '/' . $filename );

    $url = $wp_upload_dir['url'] . '/' . basename( $filename );

    $attachment = array(
        'guid' => $url, 
        'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
        'post_title' => preg_replace( '/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename( $filename ) ),
        'post_content' => 'weblogo',
        'post_status' => 'inherit'
    );


    $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $url, 37 );
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
    $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $url );
    wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );  

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
if (isset($_FILES['ed_header_logo'] ) && !empty($_FILES['ed_header_logo']['name']) )

    {  

    $uploadedfile = $_FILES['ed_header_logo'];

    $upload_name = $_FILES['ed_header_logoe']['name'];

    $uploads = wp_upload_dir();
    $filepath = $uploads['path']."/$upload_name";

if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_handle_upload' ) )
    {
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
    }
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );

    $upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => false );
    //$attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file, $new_post );
    $movefile = wp_handle_upload( $uploadedfile, $upload_overrides );
    //print_r($movefile);
    if ( $movefile && !isset( $movefile['error'] ) ) {

    $file = $movefile['file'];
    $url = $movefile['url'];
    $type = $movefile['type'];

    //media_handle_upload( $file_handler, 0 );
    $attachment = array(
    'post_mime_type' => $type ,
    'post_title' => $upload_name,
    'post_content' => 'Image for '.$upload_name,
    'post_status' => 'inherit'
    );

    $attach_id=wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file, 0);
    $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $file );
    wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );

    }
```

Comment: so thanks , how can i resize or crop this image ? 


i search in internet but was not find result !


(i shoud have 15 point to do like your nice post )

Comment: can u see this topic ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31710944/send-comment-in-wordpress-keeps-hold-loading

Comment: have you used comment_form() function?

Comment: i am unable to add comment on that question :(

Comment: this problem is for all themes (i changed to sahifa , 2015 ,2015 themes) but problem was not  solved ! (this problem is for users in localhost (wp admin can send comment))